# Model is not loaded by Controller in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

So here is my code -

**Controller**

```
public function addCategory() {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE) {
        $this->load->model("categories");
        echo $this->categories->addCategory();
    }
}
```

**Model -**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Categories extends CI_Model {

    // Retrieves all category names and id's
    function getCategories() {

    }

    // Add category to database. If there are errors returns message to AJAX controller
    function addCategory() {
        return "yeah";
        das
        $categoryName = $_POST['categoryName'];
        $parentCategory = $_POST["parentCategory"];
        $error = "";
        if(isset($categoryName) && isset($parentCategory) && $categoryName != "") {
            $query = $this->db->get_where("categories", array("name" => $categoryName));
            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $error = "Category with that name already exists!";
            }
            else {
                $data = array(
                    'name' => $categoryName,
                    'parent' => $parentCategory
                );
                $this->db->insert('categories', $data);
            }
        }
        else {
            $error = "Category Name can't be empty.";
        }
        if($error != "") {
            return $error;
        }
        else {
            return "Success! Category has been added!";
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I specially added the return "yeah" and das, to see if it even works, but it doesn't, it just returns blank page without errors. Also, this is AJAX request and if I add the model content inside the controller it's working perfectly.

What could be the problem? If you need any other info, just give me a notice.

EDIT: Again, Das is only the thing I tried, and which didn't show any errors also, here is my current model code without unused entries -

```
// Add category to database. If there are errors returns message to AJAX controller
function addCategory() {
    $categoryName = $_POST['categoryName'];
    $parentCategory = $_POST["parentCategory"];
    $error = "";
    if(isset($categoryName) && isset($parentCategory) && $categoryName != "") {
        $query = $this->db->get_where("categories", array("name" => $categoryName));
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $error = "Category with that name already exists!";
        }
        else {
            $data = array(
                'name' => $categoryName,
                'parent' => $parentCategory
            );
            $this->db->insert('categories', $data);
        }
    }
    else {
        $error = "Category Name can't be empty.";
    }
    if($error != "") {
        return $error;
    }
    else {
        return "Success! Category has been added!";
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have syntax errors, CI usually doesn't display the error, it just shows a blank page. Try looking in your php error log.

Comment: For example, why do you have a `das` after `return "yeah";` in your `addCategory` function? Is that a syntax error?

Comment: @Jebego as I wrote, I added it specially to see if it returns any syntax error, but it didn't. Also, I'm on local machine, and I haven't added to create log files for errors, but instead show them directly.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then. Just as a tip: Instead of using `$_POST['variable'];`, you should use `$this->input->post('variable');` from CI's [input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).

Comment: Same here. @Jebego good catch. Those would not be desired in production quality code.

Comment: Well, I'm sending AJAX request, and I already tried using $this->input->post("variable"); but it didn't return anything.

Comment: Woops, my bad it does work :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename the `class name Categories to Categories_model` and name the `file as categories_model.php` .you are probably not able to access the model file because you have put the wrong class name in the model file

Comment: Cheers dude! that exactly worked! Whoa! It seems model names can't be same as class names. Cool, it seems you have some power or crystal ball, since I didn't mention my controller name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

das isn't recognized by PHP so it is silently failing saying `unexpected T_VARIABLE`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Categories extends CI_Model {

    // Retrieves all category names and id's
    function getCategories() {

    }

    // Add category to database. If there are errors returns message to AJAX controller
    function addCategory() {
        return "yeah";
        $categoryName = $_POST['categoryName'];
        $parentCategory = $_POST["parentCategory"];
        $error = "";
        if(isset($categoryName) && isset($parentCategory) && $categoryName != "") {
            $query = $this->db->get_where("categories", array("name" => $categoryName));
            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $error = "Category with that name already exists!";
            }
            else {
                $data = array(
                    'name' => $categoryName,
                    'parent' => $parentCategory
                );
                $this->db->insert('categories', $data);
            }
        }
        else {
            $error = "Category Name can't be empty.";
        }
        if($error != "") {
            return $error;
        }
        else {
            return "Success! Category has been added!";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I did read it to the end. I'm pointing out your syntax error. You may have added it after you tried it using AJAX but it is still a syntax error.